# Locomotive scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, locomotive-scroll, locomotivejs

I have  tag in my website and when click it, needs to move to one of bottom div. It's working fine and website has Locomotive scroll enabled.

**The problem**

After moving to the bottom section, it cannot scroll to top of the page. and showing some blank when scrolling bottom.

I tried to fix with following but I don't think it's CSS issue.

```
html.has-scroll-smooth {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

[data-load-container] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4gh0cas/).

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a fix. just add this attribute to a tag "data-scroll-to"